# How to know which resource is being used when using SimPy's AnyOf method?

Tags: python, simpy

In my program, agents need to use some **specific** resources. I want to call all of the resources that are assigned for an agent at the same time and use the first available one.

### Think about 3 servers and 4 agents.

`agent1` can use `server1`,

`agent2` can use `server1` and `server2`,

`agent3` can use `server2` and `server3`,

`agent4` can use `server3`

I am creating requests like below:

```py
{server: server.request() for server in agent_2_server_list}

output:
{<simpy.resources.resource.Resource at 0x7fd091b215e0>: <Request() object at 0x7fd091d51d00>,
 <simpy.resources.resource.Resource at 0x7fd091b21700>: <Request() object at 0x7fd091d51b50>}
```

I am using `env.any_of([request1, request2])` to use any of the above requests. However, I need to know which resource is used so that I can release it afterward. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

env.any_of returns a dict of the first events that fired.  Remember that both events can fire at the same time.  Also remember that if only one event fires, the second event is still pending.  So if you only want one event to fire you will have to check if both events fired and release one, or if only one event fired, to cancel the second event.

here is a example

```
"""
example of getting the first avalable resouce from 2 resouce pools

prorammer Michael R. Gibbs
"""
import simpy

def seat(env, id, smokingRes, nonSmokingRes):
    """
    Main process of getting the first avaialbe table
    from one of two resouce pools (smoking, non smoking)
    """

    # make a request from both resouce pools
    print(env.now, id, "waiting for a table")
    smokeReq = smokingRes.request()
    nonSmokeReq = nonSmokingRes.request()

    # wait for one of the requests to be filled
    seat = yield env.any_of([smokeReq,nonSmokeReq])
    
    seatList = list(seat.keys())

    # it is possible that both resources are avaliable
    # and both request get filled
    seated = seatList[0]

    if len(seatList) > 1:
        # both requests got filled, need to release one
        print(env.now, id, "both were available, releasing one")
        if seated == smokeReq:
            nonSmokingRes.release(nonSmokeReq)
        else:
            smokingRes.release(smokeReq)
    else:
        # only one request was filled, need to cancel the other request
        print(env.now, id, 'got a seat, cancel other request')
        if smokeReq in seatList:
            nonSmokeReq.cancel()
        else:
            smokeReq.cancel()

    yield env.timeout(5)
    if seated == smokeReq:
        smokingRes.release(seated)
    else:
        nonSmokingRes.release(seated)
    print(env.now, id, "released seat")

def test(env, smokingRes, nonSmokingRes):
    """
    test when four people want 2 tables
    """
    env.process(seat(env,1,smokingRes,nonSmokingRes))
    yield env.timeout(1)
    env.process(seat(env,2,smokingRes,nonSmokingRes))
    yield env.timeout(1)
    env.process(seat(env,3,smokingRes,nonSmokingRes))
    yield env.timeout(1)
    env.process(seat(env,4,smokingRes,nonSmokingRes))


env = simpy.Environment()
smokingRes = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=1)
nonSmokingRes = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=1)

env.process(test(env,smokingRes,nonSmokingRes))


env.run(until=100)

print ('done')
```

Comment: That's exactly my problem. 
The output of `server_request = yield self.env.any_of(server_requests)` is `<ConditionValue {<Request() object at 0x7fc2e1de54d0>: None}>`. I have a dictionary to track server resources and requests. From that dictionary I try to find which resource is being used but `<ConditionValue {<Request() object at 0x7fc2e1de54d0>: None}>`doesn't give me much information. server_request.events gives me the request like `<Request() object at 0x7fc2e1de54d0>` but since I don't know which one is being used I can't release any of them.

Comment: yes, server_request  is a dict of the events that fired, remember more then one event can fire at the same time.  you can convert the dict to a list of requests with req_list = list(server_request .keys()).  The None value is the value the event returns when it fires.  resource request do not use this so that is why it is None.  Also remember that you will need to deal with the request that you do not use, either releasing it, or canceling it.

I also updated my answer with a any_of example

Comment: Great Michael. Thank you. I don't think "when any_of used, more than one event can fire at the same time" is mentioned on the documentation. I hope this post can serve to explain this concept.